# Extending rails classes from engines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm playing around with creating a simple plugin system for my app. Currently, i wan't to be able to extend my activerecord models from inside the engine files.

Let's say i have a following model:

```
# /my_app/app/models/post.rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

What i want to achieve is to be able to put a file, for example, `/my_app/example_engine/app/example_engine/models/post.rb` which will add some methods to my `Post` class. I was trying to make that by putting a following content to that file:

```
# /my_app/example_engine/app/example_engine/models/post.rb
Post.class_eval do
  def new_method
    "hello"
  end
end
```

But it seems that it's not a proper way of doing this cause it's not working. I probably lack some elementary knowledge about ruby classes or how rails works so i would be really thankful if anyone could help me with that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it necessary to keep the base class as opposed to simply subclassing?

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with subclassing, I would recommend doing the following

Have your engine extend the base class under a namespace such as

```
    module MyEngine
      class Post < Post
        .....
      end
    end
```

No need to eval, just inherit from the base class and extend it as you need.

Comment: Actually i'm just trying to make it working using whatever solution possible :) Is there something wrong with keeping the base class instead of subclassing?

Comment: Ohh and what's more important - it's really important for me to not touch the root app. All i want to do is to include a engine in Gemfile. Nothing more.

Comment: I'd avoid using class eval or eval in general if you can. In your case i'll rewrite what I answered since I answered in the opposite sense of your question

Comment: The problem is that your solution is good when i have just one engine or i'm the only user of the app. My goal is to create a base app which can be extended by plugins (modules) and doing so by editing something in the core root app each time i want to add a new engine is not a good solution in this case.

Comment: Oh, i can see your edit and it looks really interesting but i'm not able to make it work. Here is my source code: https://github.com/mbajur/eval_test/tree/julio

Comment: gotcha, will have to revisit this.  This is purely opinion based but you may want to look into actually isolating out all common needed functionality into an engine you can share among your engines as opposed to each one writing to a singular file.